Is it possible to reduce the influence that a bone will have before parenting with automatic weights?
I can see that in the deform section in the bone properties tab there are options to reduce the "envelope weight" of a bone but are there similar options for bones that aren't of the envelope type? Maybe even an add-on that does this would be helpful.

You could reduce the weight afterwards (for example in Weight Paint mode > Weights > Levels)
